# Troubles with Heroku SSL on a rails app : 'Only one SNI endpoint is allowed per app'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, deployment

quick question: I'm trying to set up ssl to an app, using heroku and Gandi. Notice that I followed le wagon tuto (https://vimeo.com/209534466).

Everything went smooth until the last step when I ran the following code:

`heroku certs:add all.crt myserver.key --app chrisnopa-my-site`

It gives me this:

`Resolving trust chain... done
Adding SSL certificate to ⬢ chrisnopa-my-site... !
 ▸    Only one SNI endpoint is allowed per app (try certs:update instead).`

It's quite a bit unclear to me since I'm not that familiar with Heroku stuff...  Any idea on how to fix it or any lead?

Answer (score 0):

with that command you are creating an ssl certificate inside the aws server instance.

SSL Certificate is a file including the encryption key to be used in to encrypt messages sent with ssl.

[The following guide explains how to set up multiple `ssl endpoints` with heroku.](https://www.codeography.com/2016/11/07/multiple-ssl-endpoints-on-heroku-with-sni.html)

The alternative is to delete the current `ssl certificate` or use that certificate for the `ssl` configuration. You probably have already an `ssl endpoint`.

as described [in the guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#remove-certificate) you can delete the certificate from the server

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for us was to first delete the existing SSL certificate from the Heroku app, and then add the new one.

Apparently Heroku doesn't automatically replace the old one with the new one.